# Soundcloud API support pagination?

Tags: ruby, api, pagination, soundcloud, partitioning

How would I use the "linked_partitioning=1" to call on the "next_href" in the response? I see the next_href in the response, but I don't know what to do next?

:\ Please help 
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make a call to this url.

Read more here:

- https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/offset-pagination-deprecated
- https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#errors

EDIT:

According to your comments, i have added some code in JS, which print all tracks from Boilerroom.

Using SoundCloud SDK + jquery, this is an excerpt.

```
function linked(obj){
if(obj.next_href)
    {
    loadMore(obj.next_href);
    console.log(obj.next_href)
    }

    $.each(obj.collection, function( key, val ) {
    $('#result').append(val.title + '<br/>');
  });    

}

function loadMore(url){
    $.getJSON( url, function( tracks ) {
        linked (tracks);
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/tehd02y6/

Comment: idk how do i do that? :\ @bnz
I'm not sure how to make a call to a http: link...like where would i put the next_href as a value.
Could you write it out how it would look?

Comment: wait, I think I know what you're hinting at :\

Comment: This depends on your application, i am not a Ruby dev, but you can write a loop to fetch all or just load the next things, when you will need them. It depends on your application.

Comment: are you a python dev... or js? or what do you use? @bnz

Comment: i have added some logic and an example in JS, take a look at the link. for the future, i would like to ask you kindly to read how stackoverflow works, please come up with your code - and don't ask the same question twice.