# How to get all tracks from soundcloud

Tags: soundcloud

I need to get all tracks from SoundCloud server. Now I am getting approx 200 hundred Track using limit. can help me anyone, see the my code below.

```
$tracks_json = file_get_contents('http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=Here_My_CLIENT_IDc&limit=50&linked_partitioning=1');

$tracks = json_decode($tracks_json);

$ct=1;
foreach ($tracks as $track)
{
    echo $ct.'.) '.strip_tags($track->title).'<br>';

    $ct++;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Soundcloud API support pagination?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327076/soundcloud-api-support-pagination)

Comment: this answer might help you - take a look on the fiddle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327076/soundcloud-api-support-pagination